# Como creo mi interfaz de administracion en Django 1.9

Tags: django

La verdad es que soy bastante nuevo en Django y pues me gusta el framework pero no consigo o no logro entender como poder crear una interfaz de administracion (Se que Django trae una por defecto pero no me gusta) asi que, espero que me ayuden, saludos.

Comment: Debes crear un superusuario con el comando: python manage.py createsuperuser

Comment: luego activar el servidor de desarrollo y entrar a la url: {tuurl}/admin

Comment: http://librosweb.es/libro/django_1_0/capitulo_17/crear_vistas_de_administracion_personalizadas.html mira este enlace, creo que es lo que buscas

Comment: Bastante amplia la pregunta, Koroa. Si tienes algún problema específico implementando tu propia interfaz de administración, haz tu pregunta (o preguntas) siguiendo esta guía: [mcve].

Comment: Gracias por sugerir la guia, un saludo.